Why are we unable to add values to Picklist field in Custom Metadata in a 2nd generation package (2GP)?
Can we not add values to a picklist field under Custom Metadata in Second-Generation Managed Package. We have the Subscriber editable option true for Field Manageability, but it doesn't allow us to add new values.


Are you trying to add them in the package itself, or as a subscriber of the package (installed on an org)?

As a subscriber of the package which is installed in the org. As you can see from the screenshot above, there's no option to add New values

This is how picklists in custom metadata types work. The assumption that Salesforce appeared to make here is that only the package developer knows what metadata options make sense.
Setting the field as subscriber managed simply means that the subscriber can change this field's value on any unprotected custom metadata type records that are part of the package, not that the subscriber can change the picklist options.
The following is a quote from the documentation:

Subscribers to a released managed package that contains a custom metadata type with a picklist field can’t add, delete, or deactivate values from that picklist.

It is also worth noting that a package developer has some restrictions over how they can change this picklist's values too - deleting them, for example, is not permitted. Another quote, from the same documentation:

Developers who release a managed package that contains a custom metadata type with a picklist field can add picklist values but not delete or deactivate them.

